# Busca dinamica com filter

Tags: javascript, json

Preciso fazer uma busca dinamica de um json, até então funciona porem ela só acha se eu digitar no input a palavra exata que há dentro do json, gostaria q eu escrevesse "i" e começasse a parecer os resultados com a letra "i"

```
  let pesquisa = $('#searchBar')


  pesquisa.keyup(() => {

     let searchVal = pesquisa.val()

     let search = dataJson.filter(search => search.assunto == searchVal || search.projeto == searchVal || search.empresa == searchVal) 
     console.log(search)
     listNotes(search)
})
```

o dataJson tem esse escopo:

```
        {
        "id_note": "2019",
        "data": "2021-09-01",
        "start_hour": "08:59",
        "end_hour": "12:15",
        "tipo": "teste",
        "assunto": "",
        "empresa": "teste",
        "obs": "teste",
        "id_usuario": "3",
        "projeto": "",
        "duracao": "03:16",
        "log_hora_start": "12:15",
        "log_hora_end": "12:15",
        "data_br": "01\/09\/2021"
    }
```

Comment: 1- Onde diz busca dinâmica, não seria busca parcial? 2- Aqui *"preciso fazer uma busca dinamica de um **json**"* mas aqui `let search = dataJson.filter(search =>.....` o trata como um array e posteriormente o descreve com um objeto literal, qual é o formato de `dataJson`? Favor [edit] a pergunta e elucubrar as questões levantadas.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi, o dataJson deveria ser um array, certo?

Se sim, o problema é a comparação que você está fazendo. Utilize o método `includes` da string.

A sua pesquisa dentro do filter deveria ser mais ou menos assim.

```js
pesquisa.keyup(() => {
  const searchVal = pesquisa.val()

  const result = dataJson.filter(
   ({ assunto, projeto, empresa }) => 
     assunto.includes(searchVal) ||
     projeto.includes(searchVal) ||
     empresa.includes(searchVal)
  )

  console.table(result)
  listNotes(result)
})
```